# Cannot connect to WMS server from QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, australia

I am trying to connect to a WMS server from this [location](https://www.data.vic.gov.au/data/dataset/locality-boundaries-road-polygon-vicmap-admin) through QGIS. I get the message

> The server you are trying to connect to does not seem to be a WMS
>   server. Please check the URL

I am trying to connect by adding a layer from a WMS server.

Comment: What QGIS version and OS?

Answer (score 7):

The URL you get (WMS request):

```
http://services.land.vic.gov.au/catalogue/publicproxy/guest/dv_geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&LAYERS=VMADMIN_AD_LOCALITY_AREA_POLYGON&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SRS=EPSG%3A4283&BBOX=141%2C-39%2C150%2C-34
```

WMS request decomposed:

```
- Service endpoint: http://services.land.vic.gov.au/catalogue/publicproxy/guest/dv_geoserver/wms?
- Service type: SERVICE=WMS
- Service version: VERSION=1.1.1
- Operation type: REQUEST=GetMap
- Picture width: WIDTH=512
- Picture height: HEIGHT=512
- Layer(s): LAYERS=VMADMIN_AD_LOCALITY_AREA_POLYGON
- Style: STYLES=
- Format: FORMAT=image/png
- Coordinate system: SRS=EPSG:4283
- Bounding box: BBOX=141,-39,150,-34
```

The URL you need to add in QGIS WMS connection (endpoint):

```
http://services.land.vic.gov.au/catalogue/publicproxy/guest/dv_geoserver/wms?
```

[image]

The layer you need to select after connecting is:

```
VMADMIN_AD_LOCALITY_AREA_POLYGON
```

[image]

[image]

You could use the same URL to add WFS connection because the performance looks incredible slow to me...

Answer (score 1):

The link works if you removed all the queries in the WMS URL link as follows:
http://services.land.vic.gov.au/catalogue/publicproxy/guest/dv_geoserver/wms

However, the above link detailed data that may take long time to load. You may need to select a specified data instead of loading everything.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to connect to a WMS Server only. You can directly put the WMS url in Brower to see if it is working. You need to add some more parameters along the url like layers, bbox, format, width, height, SRS, version, request, service ....

Other parameters can be checked from [here](http://geospatialearth.in/ms4w.php#WMS).

If you version as 1.3.0 along with CRS, you can check the error in browser itself provided the url servers WMS.